# Why can't I map through an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I want to map through an array but I'm getting an error: 
TypeError: locationAddress.map is not a function

I'm new to React and React Hooks. I've been trying to simplify the array but no luck.
Any ideas why this is not working?

Edit: I tried all the changes in the answers so far but the error persists.
I included more code and the package.json file.
I tried deactivating some functions like the useEffect and now the error only shows when I try to type in the input field that is being mapped.

**Found the solution:**

```
const [locationAddress, setLocationAddress] = 
useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ([{ ...state, ...newState }]),
    [{
    address: "",
    name: ""
}]);
```

I used 'useReducer' and tried putting some '[]' around { ...state, newState } and now it works.
Thanks for those who answered.
**The useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values. It also lets you optimize performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.**

```
    import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

import { Form, Button, Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

const FormData = () => {

    const [locationAddress, setLocationAddress] = 
    useReducer(
        (state, newState) => ([{ ...state, ...newState }]),
        [{
        address: "",
        name: ""
    }]);

    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(locationAddress))

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchLocation = async () => {
            for(let i = 0; i < locationAddress.length; i++) {
                const res = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
                    params: {
                        address: locationAddress[i].address,
                        key: 'MyAPIKey'
                    }
                });
                setLocationAddress(res.data);
                setCoordinates(res.data.results[0].geometry.location);
                console.log('Coordinates: ' + JSON.stringify(coordinates));    
            }
        }
        fetchLocation();
    }, [coordinates, locationAddress]);

    const onChangeAddress = e => setLocationAddress({ ...locationAddress, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <ul>
                    {locationAddress && locationAddress.map(({address, name}, index) => 
                        <li key={index}>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Label htmlFor="address">Enter location</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" name="address" id="address" value={address} onChange={onChangeAddress} />
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Label htmlFor="name">Enter name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" name="name" id="name" value={name} onChange={onChangeAddress} />
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Button variant="secondary" type="submit">Remove friend</Button>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="secondary" type="submit">Add friend</Button>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default FormData;
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "map-calculator-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: is locationAddress an array? make sure it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks right.
try this one using `ocationAddress && locationAddress.map()`

```
               <ul>
                {locationAddress && locationAddress.map((location, index) => 
                    <li key={index}>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label for="address">Enter location</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" name="address" id="address" value={address} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label for="address">Enter name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" name="address" id="address" value={address} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Button variant="secondary" type="submit">Remove friend</Button>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Vahid, tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as is, since your `locationAddress` is an array of an object initialised by `useState` hook.

> I replicated your code with few adjustments:

1. Your location during `.map()`, need destructuring into `address` and `name`. Then only you could access it in `FormControl` the way you have it now. (OR change the `value`s of your `FormControl` to `location.address` and `location.name`.
2. Added a default data into `locationAddress` to make sure you can access it for testing purposes.

**The code snippet**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [locationAddress, setLocationAddress] = useState([{
    address: "US",
    name: "John Doe"
}]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {
          locationAddress.map(({ address, name }) => <span>{`${address}-${name}`}</span>)
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Before you use hooks, make sure your `react` is at `v16.8.0` (or higher).

```
The sandbox [link][1].


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-hellman-u4vc5
```

Comment: Thanks, @pritam for your answer. Unfortunately, the code is still not working and the error remains the same. I wonder if there's a problem with the React Hooks!? I made available my package.json.
I tried removing the Bootstrap code, still, get the error...
I'll try next removing the React Hooks and use a class component with state.